# Qual é a diferença entre DirectoryIterator e FileSystemIterator?

Tags: php, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

No PHP, existe a classe [DirectoryIterator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

> The DirectoryIterator class provides a simple interface for viewing the contents of filesystem directories.

Também existe [FileSystemIterator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php), que a documentação só dá essa descrição:

> The Filesystem iterator

Na sinopse da classe, mostra que `FileSystemIterator` herda `DirectoryIterator`.

Para mim, aparentemente, as duas fazem a mesma coisa, mas a documentação nos dá a impressão de serem duas coisas diferentes.

Mas, afinal de contas, qual é a diferença entre elas?

Comment: Alguma coisa me diz que, só pra variar, são conceitualmente errados, pelo menos na nomenclatura :D

Comment: @bigown por que seriam "conceitualmente errados"? qual deles que está errado?

Comment: Só escrevi "alguma coisa me diz" :P Mas se diretório é algo que faz parte de um sistema de arquivo, essa herança tá esquisita... Mas não estou dizendo que tá tudo errado lá, nem teria como dizer sem entender.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A explicação do Rubens Ribeiro, autor do [blog PHP](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/percorrer-diretorios-e-arquivos.html#dir_tipo5) está muito boa:

**DirectoryIterator**

> A classe `DirectoryIterator` implementa a interface `Iterator`, ela
>   possui os métodos para manipular o "ponteiro" para o item percorrido.
>   Por exemplo, possui o método `rewind` para voltar para a primeira
>   posição. Além disso, como implementa a interface `SeekableIterator`,
>   possui o método `seek`, que move o ponteiro para uma posição desejada.

**FilesystemIterator**

> A classe `FilesystemIterator` que estende a classe
>   `DirectoryIterator`, e oferece recursos adicionais. Por exemplo,
>   informar flags binárias para obter alguns comportamentos, tais como:
>
> - Ignorar o "." e ".."
> - Seguir links simbólicos
> - Especificar o tipo de retorno do método `current` (usado em iterações com `foreach`), etc.

**GlobIterator**

Apesar de não está na sua pergunta, acho interessante falar que também existe a classe `GlobIterator`.

> A classe `GlobIterator` estende a classe `FilesystemIterator` e
>   oferece o recurso adicional de percorrer itens a partir de uma
>   expressão, assim como mostrado com a função glob. Porém, por algum
>   motivo desconhecido, o iterador não possui um comportamento semelhante
>   ao proposto pela opção `GLOB_BRACE`.

**Recomendação de uso**

O uso destas classes é recomendado, pois elas oferecem os mesmos recursos que `opendir`, `readdir` e `closedir` (e alguns novos), e está alinhado com o modelo Orientado a Objetos, para onde os recursos do `PHP` tem caminhado. A única desvantagem é a incompatibilidade com versões antigas do `PHP` (inferiores à versão 5).

**Diferença**

`DirectoryIterator` é uma extensão de `SplFileInfo` e o `FilesystemIterator` é uma extensão de `DirectoryIterator`. E os dois implementam `Iterator`, `Traversable`, `SeekableIterator`.

Exemplo `DirectoryIterator`:

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__);
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
  if (!$fileinfo->isDot())
    var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
}
```

Examplo `FilesystemIterator`:

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__);
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
  echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
}
```

Retirei os exemplos dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532701/5327226) do stackoverflow em inglês.

Leia o artigo completo em: [Percorrer Diretórios e Arquivos com PHP](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/percorrer-diretorios-e-arquivos.html#dir_tipo5).

Comment: +1 obrigado pela resposta ;)

Answer (score 2):

`DiretoryIterator` e `FileSystemIterator` são dois iteradores pertencentes à biblioteca SPL do PHP.

## DirectoryIterator

`DirectoryIterator` implementa a interface `SeekableIterator` e estende `SplFileInfo`. Esta classe fornece uma interface simples para visualização de conteúdo de diretórios de arquivos.

## FileSystemIterator

A classe `FileSystemIterator` herda `DirectoryIterator`, porém existe o acréscimo dos métodos `setFlags` e `getFlags`, que pode mudar o comportamento dessa classe.

Veja abaixo alguma dessas flags:

```
CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME
CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
CURRENT_AS_SELF
CURRENT_MODE_MASK

KEY_AS_PATHNAME
KEY_AS_FILENAME

FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
KEY_MODE_MASK
NEW_CURRENT_AND_KEY
SKIP_DOTS
UNIX_PATHS
```

Um ponto importantes, que não foram citados em outras respostas, é que `FileSystemIterator`, além de seguir links simbólicos, também **não lista** os pontos (`.` e `..`) como sendo parte do sistema de arquivos, e isso porque a flag `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` vem ativada por padrão no `construtor`.

As flags prefixadas por `CURRENT_AS_` tem como finalidade alterar o retorno da função `FilesystemIterator::current` (que faz parte da implementação do `SeekableIterator` ou `Iterator`), e as prefixadas por `KEY_AS_` altera o comportamento do que é retornado no método `FilesystemIterator::key`. Assim, o argumento `$key` do `foreach` provavelmente será afetado, já que o mesmo utiliza internamente esses métodos para retornar os valores de iteração quando usado com uma implementação de `Iterator`.

Veja mais sobre iteradores:

- [Como verificar se um valor é iterável pelo foreach em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176686/como-verificar-se-um-valor-%C3%A9-iter%C3%A1vel-pelo-foreach-em-php)
- [O que é Iterator?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164232/o-que-%C3%A9-iterator)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta está no primeiro comentário da página do [FileSystemIterator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php).

> When you iterate using DirectoryIterator each "value" returned is the same DirectoryIterator object. The internal state is changed so when you call isDir(), getPathname(), etc the correct information is returned. If you were to ask for a key when iterating you will get an integer index value.
>
> FilesystemIterator (and RecursiveDirectoryIterator) on the other hand returns a new, different SplFileInfo object for each iteration step. The key is the full pathname of the file. This is by default. You can change what is returned for the key or value using the "flags" arguement to the constructor.

E eu traduzo, com adaptações:

"Quando você itera usando `DirectoryIterator` cada "valor" retornado é o mesmo objeto `DirectoryIterator`. O estado interno é mudado, então quando você chama `isDir()`, `getPathname()`, etc, o valor correto é retornado. Se vc fosse usar as chaves quando tiver iterando você iria obter uma valor inteiro.

`FileSystemIterator` por outro lado retorna um novo objeto `SplFileInfo` para cada passo da interação. A chave, também é diferente, é o caminho completo do arquivo. Isto por padrão. Você pode mudar o que é retornado pela chave usando o argumento das "flags" no construtor."