# O que é Iterator?

Tags: c++, terminologia, iterator, stl

Estudando a `STL` em C++, quase sempre me deparo com o termo `iterator`, exemplo:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
```

Qual a função de um `iterator`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É o mecanismo usado para "andar", elemento por elemento, por uma coleção de dados. É uma forma abstrata e genérica de tratar o avanço entre os elementos dessa coleção. Esse avanço pode se dar de várias formas, inclusive ao contrário.

O funcionamento exato depende de cada tipo de dado, o importante é que se um tipo possui um iterador em conformidade com a linguagem toda operação que iteração poderá ser feita com aquele objeto. Não importa para ele a complexidade da operação, nem como ela deverá ser feita. É uma forma independente da implementação de acessar os dados da coleção.

Ele possui os métodos [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) e [`end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) pra indicar onde começa e onde termina a iteração.

Exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    vector<int> vetor;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) vetor.push_back(i);
    for (auto it = vetor.begin(); it != vetor.end(); it++) cout << ' ' << *it;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fY1BoU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nnyahmbz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/Iterate.cpp).

Se você está criando um tipo que é uma coleção de dados, muito provavelmente deverá implementar um iterador para esse tipo. Existe uma série de regras a serem seguidas.

[Documentação da biblioteca de iteração do C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Comment: `for (int it : vetor)` ou `for (auto it : vetor) cout << ' ' << it;` é válido no C++11 (um alias). https://ideone.com/Qfy5Vd É menos verboso... só ñ dá para controlar o `i`.

Comment: @Hand1Cloud É verdade.

Answer (score 5):

O iterador é também conhecido como cursor que prover uma forma sequencial de acessar os elementos de uma coleção sem expor sua representação interna.

Se você sabe que o seu List é um ArrayList, então não há problemas em usar o índice em vez de usar um Iterator. Para todos os outros tipos (LinkedList, Set, Map etc.) você tem de usar o Iterator.

E de qualquer maneira você continua a usar o for:

```
 for valor in sequencia:
     print(valor)
```

Ele pode ser usado quando:

- Queremos isolar o uso de uma estrutura de dados de sua representação interna de forma a poder mudar a estrutura sem afetar quem a usa
- Para determinadas estruturas, pode haver formas diferentes de caminhamento ("traversal") e queremos encapsular a forma exata de caminhamento
- A mera substituição de um iterador permite caminhar numa coleção de várias formas

Existem ainda dois tipos de iteradores: `interno` e `externo`.

*Com iterador interno, o cliente passa uma operação a ser desempenhada pelo iterador e este o aplica a cada elemento.*

*Com iterador externo (mais flexíveis), o cliente usa a interface do iterador para caminhar mas ele mesmo (o cliente) processa os elementos da coleção*

Neste caso um iterador interno só é utilizado quando um iterador externo é difícil de implementar.

Fontes:

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterador 
http://www.guj.com.br/t/qual-e-a-vantagem-do-iterator/35565