# Obter uma lista com os primeiros múltiplos de um número

Tags: python, lista

Eu preciso fazer um programa que determine os 5 primeiros múltiplos de 3, e queria colocar os valores dos 5 primeiros números em um variável, porém não sei como fazer isso. Eu tentei fazer:

```py
for index in lista:
    while 1 <= index <=5:
        numeros.append(lista[index])
        index == index +1
```

Mas isso não funcionou. Também tentei:

```py
numeros = []
lista = []
for n in range(1, 100):
    if n % 3 == 0:
        lista.append(n)
        print(lista)
```

Comment: Não bastaria apenas algo como `lista = [3*1, 3*2, 3*3, 3*4, 3*5]`?

Answer (score 2):

Para ter os N primeiros múltiplos de 3, basta criar uma lista com o resultado de `3 * 1`, `3 * 2`, `3 * 3`, etc, até `3 * N`.

Então basta que o `range` vá de 1 a N, e você insere o resultado da multiplicação de 3 por cada elemento do `range`:

```
n = 5 # quantidade de múltiplos
multiplos = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    multiplos.append(3 * i)
print(multiplos)
```

Lembrando que [em um `range` o valor final não é incluso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), por isso coloquei `n + 1`, para que ele possa ir até o enésimo múltiplo.

Outra opção é usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
n = 5 # quantidade de múltiplos
multiplos = [ 3 * i for i in range(1, n + 1) ]
print(multiplos)
```

Ou, usando [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para mapear cada valor do `range` para o seu triplo:

```
n = 5 # quantidade de múltiplos
multiplos = list(map(lambda i: i * 3, range(1, n + 1)))
print(multiplos)
```

---

Por fim, você também pode gerar o `range` com os próprios múltiplos. Basta começar em 3 (que é o primeiro múltiplo), termine em `3 * N` (o enésimo múltiplo), e pule de 3 em 3 (para sempre obter o próximo múltiplo). Depois basta obter a lista diretamente dele:

```
n = 5 # quantidade de múltiplos
multiplos = list(range(3, (n * 3) + 1, 3))
#                      ^   ^^^^^^^^^^  ^
#                      |       |       |
#                      |       |       \__ passo (pular de 3 em 3)
#                      |       |
#      valor inicial __/       \__ valor final

print(multiplos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar um script que possa encontrar e listar os **5** primeiros múltiplos de **3**.
Pois bem, para resolver este problema podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
lista = list()
for i in range(3, (5 * 3) + 1, 3):
    lista.append(i)

print(lista)
```

Observe que o **for** está percorrendo o range que inicia no **menor múltiplo de 3** - que é 3 - indo até o **quinto múltiplo de 3** - que é 15 - com o passo **3**.

Ou se preferir, podes utilizar o [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
lista = [i for i in range(3, (5 * 3) + 1, 3)]
print(lista)
```

Comment: valeu ! como ainda sou bem novo com Python eu ainda tenho problemas pra imaginar diferentes maneiras de resolver o mesmo problema. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode fazer utilizando o módulo [*itertools*](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) que possui algumas funções interessantes para se trabalhar com [iteradores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164232/o-que-%C3%A9-iterator).

Iteradores em Python são simplesmente objetos que pode ser percorrido um elemento de cada vez. Para isso esses implementam o [Protocolo de iteração](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/c-api/iter.html).
Aqui é interessante apenas saber que a travessia dos elementos dum iterador é feita pelo do método built-in [next()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#next) que recupera o próximo item do iterador.

O módulo *itertools* abriga a função [`itertools.count(start= 0, step= 1)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) que cria um iterador que retorna valores uniformemente espaçados iniciando com `start` e espaçados por `step`. Como exemplo a expressão:

```
count(n,n)
```

É a expressão python para todos o múltiplos de um número `n` indo de `n` até o infinito.

Colocando em um exemplo genérico:

```
from itertools import count                          #Importa para o código o método count().

n = int(input('Digite o número:'))                   #Lê o número que será gerada a tabuada de múltiplos.
m = int(input('Digite a quantidade de múltiplos:'))  #Lê o número de múltiplos a serem gerados na tabuada.

i = count(n,n)                                       #Cria o iterador para o múltiplos de n.

for _ in range(m):                                   #Para os primeiros m múltiplos de n...
    print(next(i))                                   #...os imprime.
```

Testes:

```
Digite o número:3
Digite a quantidade de múltiplos:5
3
6
9
12
15
```

---

```
Digite o número:6
Digite a quantidade de múltiplos:20
6
12
18
24
30
36
42
48
54
60
66
72
78
84
90
96
102
108
114
120
```

Também, como sugerido nos comentários pelos usuários [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) e [Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/woss), é possível utilizar a função [islice()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) que retorna uma porção de elementos de um iterável:

```
from itertools import count, islice
 
n = int(input('Digite o número:'))                   
m = int(input('Digite a quantidade de múltiplos:')) 

print(list(islice(count(n, n), m)))
```

Teste:

```
Digite o número:3
Digite a quantidade de múltiplos:5
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Comment: Uma sugestão com `itertools`: https://ideone.com/AddTZ8

Comment: @hkotsubo: Valeu depois do almoço vou colocar na resposta.

Comment: Eu: "Comentarei que pode usar o `islice` para obter os N valores... ih, já tem uma sugestão do @hkotsubo, quer ver que é usando o `islice`?" hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Seu código ta funcionando. Mas tem um jeito mais prático de fazer:

```
lista = []
for n in range(3, 100, 3):
    lista.append(n)
print(lista)
```

Dessa forma você já pula de 3 em 3, sem precisar fazer checagem de resto.

Comment: bem pensado!! eu nao tinha pensado nessa opção de botar o loop pra pular de 3 em 3... valeuuu

Answer (score 0):

Esta solução resolve seu problema, é criado uma lista para armazenar os múltiplos de três `lista_multiplos = []`, o valor `num` é constante, assim um `for` multiplica `num` por cinco elementos `for n in range(1, 6):`. logo em seguida é exibido os múltiplos no laço abaixo ao primeiro. Espero que ajude :)

```py
num = 3
lista_multiplos = []
for n in range(1, 6):
    lista_multiplos.append(num*n)
for elemento in lista_multiplos:
    print(elemento)
```

Answer (score -4):

for i in range(1,11,1):

```
  print(i*3)
```