# Listar arquivos de pastas com PHP

Tags: php

Estava à a procura desta solução, em que posso navegar pelo servidor e mostrar as pastas e ficheiros, sem recorrer a BD.

isto parece-me interessante, mas como é que posso mostrar todos os ficheiros sem aparecer os 2 primeiros (.) (..)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o que me acontece, o que pretendo é que me mostre os 5 videos e ocultar os 2 primeiros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é possível fazer?

estou a usar o seguinte código

```
<?php
    $path = "../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/";
    $diretorio = dir($path);
    //echo "Lista de Arquivos do diretório '<strong>".$path."</strong>':<br />";    
    while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
        $nom_directorio = substr($arquivo,0,-4);
        $extension = substr($arquivo,-3);

        echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
              <div class='info-box'>
                <div align='center'>
                <div class='demonstrations'>
                <video width='100%' height='200' controls='controls' style='margin-top: -20px;'>
                <source src='../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/$arquivo' type='video/mp4'>
                <object data='' width='100%' height='200'>
                <embed width='100% height='200' src='../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/$arquivo'>
                </object>
                </video>
              </div>
              <br/>
              <div class='info-box-text' style='padding: 5px;'><b>".$nom_directorio."</b></div>
              <span class='info-box-text'>
                <b>EXTENSION:</b> ".$extension."
              </span>
              <div style='padding: 10px;'>
              <a href='../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/$arquivo' class='btn btn-default' rel='group' download style='margin-top: 5px;'
              title='Télécharger ".$nom_directorio."'>
              <i class='fa fa-download'></i>&nbsp;
              </a>
              &nbsp;
              <a href='Suprimer_video.php?nome=$arquivo&division=$categorie' class='btn btn-default onClick='return confirma();'>
              <i class='fa fa-trash'></i>
              </a>
              </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.info-box-content -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.info-box -->
            </div>
            ";
    }
    $diretorio -> close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer a checagem pelo nome assim `$arquivo === '.' || $arquivo === '..'`, se for qualquer um destes usa o `continue;` para pular para o proximo arquivo.

Assim deve resolver:

```
<?php
    $path = "./";
    $diretorio = dir($path);
    //echo "Lista de Arquivos do diretório '<strong>".$path."</strong>':<br />";    
   $ignorados = array(
       '.ds_store', //Arquivo de configuração de pasta do Mac
       '._.ds_s', //Arquivo de configuração/cache do Mac
       'desktop.ini', //Arquivo de configuração de pasta do Win
       'thumbs.db'  //Arquivo de cache de imagens do Win
   );

    while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
        $narq = strtolower($arquivo);

        if (in_array($narq, )) {
            continue;
        }

        $nom_directorio = substr($arquivo,0,-4);
        $extension = substr($arquivo,-3);

        echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
```

você também pode usar o `glob` para filtrar somente para extensões especificas, assim:

- Imagens:

  ```
  glob('/pasta/foobar/baz/*.{png,gif,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE)
  ```
- Videos (creio que seja o seu caso):

  ```
  glob('/pasta/foobar/baz/*.{mp4,webm,mov,mpeg,mpg}', GLOB_BRACE)
  ```

O código deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
$path = "../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/";

foreach (glob($path . '*.{mp4,webm,mov,mpeg,mpg}', GLOB_BRACE) as $arquivo) {
    $nom_directorio = substr($arquivo,0,-4);
    $extension = substr($arquivo,-3);


    echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
          <div class='info-box'>
            <div align='center'>
            <div class='demonstrations'>
            <video width='100%' height='200' controls='controls' style='margin-top: -20px;'>
            <source src='../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/$arquivo' type='video/mp4'>
            <object data='' width='100%' height='200'>
            <embed width='100% height='200' src='../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/$arquivo'>
            </object>
            </video>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class='info-box-text' style='padding: 5px;'><b>".$nom_directorio."</b></div>
          <span class='info-box-text'>
            <b>EXTENSION:</b> ".$extension."
          </span>
          <div style='padding: 10px;'>
          <a href='../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/$arquivo' class='btn btn-default' rel='group' download style='margin-top: 5px;'
          title='Télécharger ".$nom_directorio."'>
          <i class='fa fa-download'></i>&nbsp;
          </a>
          &nbsp;
          <a href='Suprimer_video.php?nome=$arquivo&division=$categorie' class='btn btn-default onClick='return confirma();'>
          <i class='fa fa-trash'></i>
          </a>
          </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.info-box-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.info-box -->
        </div>
        ";
}

?>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente em ambiente windows, testei em linux e apareceu 1 registo '.DS_S'' outro  '._.DS_S'

Comment: @Salagdo O Mac OSX gera estes arquivos, no Finder eles são invisiveis, mas o PHP consegue ver eles, vou editar o código e já lhe aviso.

Comment: @Salagdo pronto, resposta editada, modifiquei o primeiro código e adicionei um exemplo com `glob` que facilita muito mais :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileSystemIterator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.filesystemiterator.php).

A classe `FileSystemIterator` é um iterador que tem como finalidade iterar sobre uma estrutura de diretórios. Diferentemente de `DirectoryIterator` e `Diretory`, essa classe não considera `.` ou `..` no momento de listagem dos arquivos.

Veja um exemplo:

```
$iterator = new FileSystemIterator($dir);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
     echo $file->getFilename(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Nota**: Essa classe está disponível a partir da versão 5.3 do PHP.

Veja mais em:

- [Qual é a diferença entre DirectoryIterator e FileSystemIterator?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155940/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-directoryiterator-e-filesystemiterator)

Answer (score 0):

Usando a [`SPL`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.spl.php), você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../../../../SAV-Videos/Racing-Division/') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Pode ser, @GuilhermeNascimento. Fica como uma alternativa e ele decida a melhor opção, já que você já havia comentado sobre o `FileSystemIterator`.